# Attribute filter syntax for code coverage in TeamCity

Tags: .net, teamcity, mstest, dotcover

Anyone knows the syntax for excluding code from coverage in Teamcity? I am using the ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute on certain methods and want those excluded. It works well in Visual Studio but I don't understand how to get the same behavior in TeamCity. The Field I am trying to configure is located in MsTest -> .Net Coverage -> Attribute Filters:
I have tried this:

```
-:ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute
```

and this

```
-:ExcludeFromCodeCoverage
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After trying out a few variations this worked:

```
-:System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me. can you confirm that you are decorating for example `Class1` with `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` and then TeamCity does not include `Class1` in the coverage results??

Comment: the issue is I dont see the 'Attribute Filters` textarea in TeamCity. looks like you need teamcity > 7.1 (see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/JetBrains+dotCover)

Comment: As to your first comment yes I can confirm it

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you add this filter inside **Attribute Filter**:

```
-:System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute
```

[image]