# ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute with dotCover in TeamCity 7

Tags: dotcover, teamcity-7.1

I'm trying to more accurately reflect code coverage in a project I am working on but have run into a problem when it comes to Entity Framework generated classes. I'd like to exclude the constructors of these classes from coverage stats so I have added the `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` attribute to the T4 template which regenerates the classes as I would expect e.g.

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

public partial class Address
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public Address()
    {
        this.Person = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm attempting to add this at method level as there are some partial classes containing custom logic that needs to be tested and included in code coverage stats.

From what I have read the `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` should be automatically excluded when using dotCover but I'm not sure if this was true when running via TeamCity, so I included the filter as mentioned in [Attribute filter syntax for code coverage in TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482815/attribute-filter-syntax-for-code-coverage-in-teamcity) (trying both `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` and `ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute`) with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I have the same TeamCity version as yours. It works fine for me. You should check if your configuration is correct.

You should specify attribute name in the **Attribute Filters:** section. In your case the text should be :

`-:System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute`

Marked members should not be displayed (for classes) or marked green/red in you your TeamCity coverage report.

More instructions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**I had the similar issue. I excluded generated class from coverage by adding to my "Code coverage" build step:**

`-:assembly=<assembly name>*;type=*<part of generated classname>*;method=*`

Comment: This comment isn't directly related to TeamCity & DotCover, but for those using the `DotCover.exe` command line, in order to exclude code marked with the `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` attribute you should use the following `dotCover.exe analyse ... /AttributeFilters=System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute`, you do not need the `-:` syntax as with the `/Filters=` parameter.